# How to read a JSON file using the NSJSONSerialization Class Reference?

Tags: json, ios5

I need to read a JSON file using the NSJSONSerialization Class Reference, and all the examples  that I have found about the use of this class read the content from the webpage itself, instead of reading from a JSON file that has been previously created.Anyone knows how to parse from a JSON file using that class? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple, quick'n'dirty example:

```
NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foobar"
                                                     ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];
NSError *error = nil;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                          options:kNilOptions
                                            error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);
```