# Json serialization returns null value when serialize the local json file

Tags: ios, json

when i try parse the local json file it returns null value am using xcode6.2 beta and ios 8.1

I have followed this posts also [How to read a JSON file using the NSJSONSerialization Class Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582096/how-to-read-a-json-file-using-the-nsjsonserialization-class-reference)[Cocoa-Touch - How parse local Json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150595/cocoa-touch-how-parse-local-json-file])[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150595/cocoa-touch-how-parse-local-json-file)

My code is

```
    NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries"
                                                         ofType:@"json"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                error:&error];
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);

//Upto myJson string value the json file converted into string but the jsonserialization only have //the problem and the response is always null.
//please give some suggestions,
//Thanks in advance,
my json file contains this values

{
    "AD" = "Andorra";
    "AE" = "United Arab Emirates";
    "AF" = "Afghanistan";
    "AG" = "Antigua and Barbuda";
    "AI" = "Anguilla";
    "AL" = "Albania";
    "AM" = "Armenia";
}
```

Comment: Is jsonPath is nil or not??

Comment: json path is not nill, only after serialization it returns null value

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: @satheesh for future reference check your json in http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: {
    "AD": "Andorra",
    "AE": "United Arab Emirates",
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "AI": "Anguilla",
    "AL": "Albania",
    "AM": "Armenia"
}  I have add this json value too but it reurns null value

Comment: @iHulk I have used your json format but it returns null values after serialization

Comment: @Jageen thank u so much , i have tried your link and set the correct format for my json value, thanks a lot

Comment: @SatheeshKumar can you tell me your new json file, is it different from I given in my answer?

Comment: @iHulk i have missed a comma after one key value pair that creates a issue, now i chnged that, thanks for ur support

Comment: Why on earth are you converting the file to a string and back to NSData, when in the line before you read it as NSData already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json file is corrupted. Replace your json file with this and it will work

```
{
    "AD": "Andorra",
    "AE": "United Arab Emirates",
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "AI": "Anguilla",
    "AL": "Albania",
    "AM": "Armenia"
}
```

To validate your JSON file you can go for [this link](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @SatheeshKumar I have checked it, it is working fine please try to log your myJSON string. may be you are not able to read the file.

Comment: thanks for ur support, i have formatted my json value, now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Your `Json` is not valid.  [Check your Json here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

You have put following `Json` in your `JsonFile`.

```
{
    "AD" : "Andorra",
    "AE" : "United Arab Emirates",
    "AF" : "Afghanistan",
    "AG" : "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "AI" : "Anguilla",
    "AL" : "Albania",
    "AM" : "Armenia"
}
```